# Do Protestants have a biblical basis for not smashing statues of Jesus?

Tags: biblical-basis, protestantism, image-of-god

Lately, I've been checking out "Mary Worship" videos and "Praying to Saints" videos online from Protestants who protest the Catholic practice of statues of Christ and Mary. Pastors or lay Protestants oftentimes smash statues of the Mother of God to make a point.

Why do I never see them, even the most aggressive anti-Catholic, anti-Statuary Christian videos, smashing an image of our Lord?

As a Catholic, I can say if my Mary statue had a chip in it or gets old, I might just throw in the bin, maybe even break it so it fits better. I'd do the same thing with an image of the Lord, a Bible that gets old and worn, whatever. As a Catholic, I know these things are nothing.

In anti-Catholic circles, is smashing a statue of the Lord Jesus Christ just something they will not do? Is there a biblical reason for not doing so?

Comment: Could you explain what sort of 'Protestants smashing statues' you are talking about. Smashing statues they own? Wandering into random Catholic churches and smashing the statues they find there? Breaking statues they no longer have a use for?

Comment: @DJClayworth The videos usually have to do with the Worship of Mary, which Catholic definitely do not do.  Ending with the smashing of Marys Statue for what I believe to be some attempt at dramatic effect.  Non-Affiliated Christians, Baptists, and some others have done this.  the question is focused on them never shattering the Lord Jesus in statuary.  Without meaning to, in my mind, the action and the lack of action towards Mary and Jesus accordingly, seems to represent that the smashers put something into the image of our Lord, even if they do not consciously acknowledge it.

Comment: I don't think you will get an answer because you've got an incorrect assumption. I.e. that this is either common or commonly known. Where I come from I have never heard of it before this.

Comment: @jameskhoury Thanks James, perhaps I could point out the many YouTube Videos, where Mary is smashed (Again, means nothing) but it won't really help, the videos are not about Mary smashing.  Its pageantry, and never with the image of Christ, which is the point of the Question.  Biblical Worship involves sacrifice, it always has and still does.  But that's an entirely separate issue.

Comment: @Marc I would suggest that in my (possibly) limited experience that those people are a vocal minority.

Comment: @JamesKhoury I have never seen a statue of Jesus disrespected by any denomination, it seems odd compared to the number of times I've seen Mary disrespected.  I hope so, but never the less, those who do so are numerous and receive many likes.  Which begs the question, would smashing Jesus statues generate as many likes?  I know that a majority of Christians Catholic or separated brothers respect one another.  As I'm sure you do.

Comment: Why would you throw a statue of Our Lady , Our Lord or a bible into a garbage bin because they are old , torn chipped or broken? The Church has rules as to properly disposing of such blessed items. And a garbage bin it not one of them. You should rephrase your statement. Throwing a blessed sacramentals into the [garbage] bin is almost as bad as kicking a statue. Such items should be either buried or burned or disposed of in a dignified manner and treated in a dignified manner. Please learn what the church suggests before throwing them away. **"As a Catholic, I know these things are nothing?"**

Comment: @KenGraham There are items used for celebrating the Mass that are indeed to be treated with special Care.  Old Bibles, tiny figurines in your home and so on are not part of that list.  For example, I had a Catholic Bible and I saw a reference note referring to "Q" documents, I dropped it in a bin without a second thought.  If I'm in error about these created things, then I would need some link for that.  Throwing it in the wastebasket is a lot different than smashing it into bits on camera for pageantry.  These items are nothing, it is an error to apply to them something that is not there.

Comment: @KenGraham I do understand that items that are blessed by a priest should be handled as you suggest.

Comment: Edits here have changed my question to something I am not asking.  Should I delete, or ask another as an answer has been provided to something i was not asking.

Comment: @Marc I'd suggest asking a new question.  Feel free to come to [chat] if you'd like to discuss different approaches to your question that might be more helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions here - one about icons and their place in people's minds and the other is about attitudes to those who use icons.

**The Places of Icons**

The relationship of Christians to Icons (whether 2D or 3D) has always been tricky.  There was a wave of iconoclasm in Wittenberg in the 1520's that was roundly condemned by Luther and some still continue this unfortunate practice of iconoclasm.  The problem is what to do with the commandment forbidding idols.  The answer is simple - do what the ancient Jews did - they had lots of icons around the sanctuary, but they were never worshipped as gods.  Modern iconoclasts appear to ignore the fact that the commandment in question forbids the making of idols that are worshipped as gods, as distinct from either good art or something else.

Most people are sensible enough to realise that an icon is not God and that it should not be worshipped.  (There are exceptions.)

**Attitudes to Others**

The primary difference between a protestant and a Catholic is the source of authority.  Protestants believe in "Sola Scriptura" meaning that the Bible is the last court of appeal for matters of faith.  If this is true, then a good protestant will believe in freedom of choice and freedom of religion as taught by the Bible.

Freedom of religion gives all people the right to practise their beliefs without interference by others, especially the state.  This idea, leads directly to the concept of the secular state where all people are granted religious freedom, protection under the law and access to the “public square”.  The Bible provides a number of good examples of religious tolerance.

- Mark 9:38-40, Luke 9:49, 50.  Jesus tolerated other groups disconnected from His own.
- Luke 9:52-56.  Jesus refused to curse non-believers
- John 4:7-27 (Samaritan woman at the well) is a remarkable example of tolerance where Jesus made no attempt to make the woman a Jew and call her “one of us” before she became a very effective missionary.
- Rom 2:14-16 clearly says that some pagans will be saved.  This should make Christians very tolerant of unbelievers.
- Rom 14:1-23 provides an extended passage about being non-judgemental and tolerant about others’ beliefs and practices.
- 1 Cor 10:31, 32 advises Christians to give no occasion for offence to Jews or gentiles.

In much of the western world, secular government has been implemented with the aid of the modern doctrine of the separation of church and state.

Thus, iconoclasm should have no place in the practice of Christians generally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I just don't think it answers the question.  The question focuses on whether smashing images of the Virgin Mary mother of God is done very often, yet, the smashing of statues of Our Lord and Savior is almost non-existent and when it is, it's usually not Protestants but non-believing vandals.  The ones who do the smashing of our Lady (which really means nothing) seem to be addressing a point about the statue which Catholics do not relate to.  The same argument can be made towards  Statues of Jesus, yet, the smashing of Jesus, especially in videos, does not exist.

Comment: In that case, perhaps, you should re-word the question a little.  I cannot comment on what non-Christians do.  Globally, Islam contains the greatest group of iconoclasts (albeit a minority).  As stated above, there is no justification in Protestantism for iconoclasm.

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation of Rom 2:14-16 and 14:1-23. Paul in Rom 3 makes it plain that no one can be saved through keeping the law because it merely shows that we’re sinners in need of salvation - which is provided by Christ’s redemption, and is received through faith (i.e. pagans can't be saved).  With respect to Rom 14 Paul only refers to peripheral matters like food not to Christian doctrines.

Comment: Agreed on both matters.  No one is saved except by the merits of Christ alone and nothing we do earns our salvation.  However, that does not change what I said above.

Comment: Since you agree that salvation is only through faith in Christ this excludes pagans who don't have such faith, and therefore changes your interpretation of  Romans 2:14-16 where you say some pagans will be saved.

Comment: The Bible verses you refer to in your answer don't actually allow for a non-dogmatic appreciation of religious diversity. Mark 9:38-40 for instance makes it clear that those who weren't in Christ's immediate group were still His followers as they cast out demons in His name. Whilst Christians should allow for a certain degree of religious freedom in the world this is only to avoid conflict with non-believers. It's not an acceptance that their religious views have any saving merit (Romans 16:17,18 etc).

Comment: @Eddie - You are putting words in my mouth.  I did not say salvation is by our faith in Christ; but by the merits of Christ.  How were all the people saved before the Jesus' incarnation.  Jesus saved them by His merits - but all those people did not believe in Him nor confess Him.

Comment: Oh I thought you were agreeing with me when you said in your previous comment "agreed on both matters". Anyway I don't agree that anyone has been saved other than through faith in Christ. Before Christ's incarnation it was through faith in the coming Messiah who was prophesied throughout the Old Testament.

Comment: Does that mean that our faith is a "work" we do in order to be saved?

Comment: Faith is a gift of God (Eph 2:8). We of course do the believing, but coming to faith in Christ isn't something we can initiate, but rather is the Holy Spirit's doing, who regenerates us and converts us from our sinful state at enmity with God.